# Comparing contents of txt files in Python

Tags: python, file-comparison

I am trying to write a program that will open files, read the contents and compare them to other files opened. I need to show if they are Not close enough alike, Similar, or exact copies of each other. I am trying to use the filecmp module, but it's not working for me. Here's what I have so far:

```
import filecmp

#Opens selected files
file1 = open('file1.txt')
file2 = open('file2.txt')

#Compares different files
filecmp.cmp('file1','file2', shallow=False)

#Closes Files
filecmp.clear_cache()
close.file1
close.file2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: not sure about filecmp but at least call `file1.close()`.

Comment: `filecmp` will only show equal files, how are you defining 'Similar'?

Answer (score 3):

`filecmp` is the wrong tool to use
Try this instead:
1. Load the contents of each file into a list
2. Turn the lists into sets
3. Subtract one set from the other
4. The result provides the differences between the two which you can analyse.

For example:

```
list1 = set(line.strip() for line in open("file1.txt"))
list2 = set(line.strip() for line in open("file2.txt"))
diff1 = list1 - list2 # subtract 1 set from the other for the difference
diff2 = list2 - list1 # subtract 1 set from the other for the difference
save = open("diff.txt",'w') # Write file differences details for analysis
for i in diff1:
    save.write(i+'\n')
save.close()
save = open("diff2.txt",'w') # Write file differences details for analysis
for i in diff2:
    save.write(i+'\n')
save.close()
```

or look at `difflib` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('C://Desktop/a.txt', 'C://Desktop/b.txt')
True
>>>
```

In this case I have 2 text files `a.txt` and `b.txt`. Both files contain the same one line of `string`.

If I change the `string` in one of the files to something different, the output is `False`